# PushNotifications - How to Implement

Tags: android, push-notification

I am a newbie in android. I have developed few applications, but all are plain and simple, just used the built in features of android.

I was asked about push notifications, in one of my interviews and I decided to have a look at what Push Notifications are. I understand the concept of Push Notifications(I think), but whenever I read the term "Server", it's freaking me out.

I understand all the client side coding, but I don't get how to implement the server side coding. I have seen some people use XMPP, MQTT, etc., What are those? Here is my scenario and what I want to know..

Scenario ::: Let's say I have a website, with a table (the values are retrieved from database), where I update a few columns every day. I want these updates to be reflected in my android application. So, as I have read, push notifications can tell the application that there are updates available. Good. I am fine till here..

1. When the application gets the notification, should my application, contact the website and get the latest information? or will the updated information sent through Push Notification? I guess, my application would be contacting the website and get the information. Now, how do I get the data from the website? Should I get the source of the page and do some kind of parsing or something?

I will be asking more questions, as the experts clear my questions...

Sorry, if my questions are too naive, but this is the only place that can help me...

Comment: Read about Android's GCM service. Also, please don't prefix your question's title with stuff like Push-Notifications, ListView, the tags at the bottom are more than enough.

Comment: first check this this is very easy to understand from both server & android app. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15568988/1168654

Comment: Hope this helps : [GCM Tutorial Android](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Push Notifications means Google Cloud Messaging** for Android (GCM) is a service that allows you to send data from your server to your users' Android-powered device.

You can refer to this documentation

[**Google Cloud Messaging for Android**](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

**[GCM: Getting Started](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html)**

And there is also [Demo App Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/demo.html) given

Answer (score 0):

in your case you need to create HTTP web service for getting data from the server.so when you get notification about update on server side.you just need to call this web service and get the data you need to update